# Arc Lengths of Sine Curve

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am dealing with the following problem:

[image: plot]

In this sketch *d* and *e* are arc lengths.

Now I want to find the value of *a* for which:

$\dfrac{d}{2e}=0.05$

when the value of *r* is given.

I know that:

$a\sin(2\pi fb)=r$

$a\sin(2\pi fc)=r$

$b=\dfrac{1}{2f}-c$

$d=\int_b^c\sqrt{1+4\pi^2f^2a^2\cos^2(2\pi fx)}\mathrm{d}x$

$e=\int_0^\frac{1}{2f}\sqrt{1+4\pi^2f^2a^2\cos^2(2\pi fx)}\mathrm{d}x$

I have got Matlab installed on my computer, which can be helpful in this case I suppose...

Answer (score 1):

Arc length integrals can't be calculated in terms of elementary functions. Result will need to use elliptic integrals.

Straight up calculation with computer shows that equation $\frac{d}{2e} = 0.05$ can be reduced to a form:

$$ \frac{E(\pi-\arcsin(\frac{r}{a}),z)-E(\arcsin(\frac{r}{a}),z)}{4E(z)} = 0.05$$,

where $z = 1- \frac{1}{1+(2af\pi)^2}$, $E(\phi,m)$ is [elliptic integral of second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind) (EllipticE in Mathematica) and $E(m) = E(\frac{\pi}{2},m)$ is complete elliptic integral.

I wasn't able to reduce this further, because I don't have any prior experience using elliptic integrals. Maybe someone else can continue on this.

Solving this equation agrees with my numerical calculations. For example if $f=1$ and $r=1$, solving the equation gives $a \approx 1.08713$, which is a correct answer.

Comment: Can you please tell me how you found the given formula and the answer _a≈1.08713_ using Mathematica? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To avoid confusion, let me call your function $g(x)=a\sin(2\pi fx)$. Then using standard arc length formulas from calculus,

\begin{align}
d=&\int_b^c \sqrt{1+[g'(x)]^2}dx\\
e=&\int_{1\over 2f}^{1\over f} \sqrt{1+[g'(x)]^2}dx,
\end{align}
so you want to solve ${d\over 2e}=0.05$.

Are you looking for a numerical answer? If so, we need to know the parameters $a$, $b$, $c$, and $f$.

Comment: I am looking for a numerical answer for variable _a_, when parameters _b_, _c_ and _f_ are known. At the moment these three parameters are still to be determined; so instead of just getting the numerical answer from SE, I'd like to know how I can obtain it by myself using for example Matlab.